# What does opinion-based exactly mean in this community?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

My [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74952/how-does-liz-cheneys-losing-the-republican-primary-impact-the-future-of-the-gop) was closed as opinion-based. I cannot understand how can this question be opinion-based.

> How does Liz Cheney's losing the Republican primary impact the future
> of the GOP?

The question asks about a fact that has happened and there is no partiality or position taking. Please let me know what's wrong with this question.

Comment: I personally would have voted to close as "predictions for future events" because... well, that's what it is. We can't predict how this will impact the future of the GOP. We can *guess*, but we won't actually *know* until it happens, and this isn't a site for guesswork.

Comment: I VTC mostly because the title and half the body Qs rather asked for predictions of the future "How does Liz Cheney's losing the Republican primary impact the **future** of the GOP?" "How will it impact the **future** of the Republican party and 2024 presidential elections?" In the meantime, the Q was edited to leave just "What does this loss mean for the GOP?" I'm more ho-hum about that as it's also a bit open-ended, but I might have not VTC if it asked just that.

Comment: it means: you didn't subscribe to the opposite opinion, so shut up

Answer (score 3):

Because what it means is an opinion and there is no one correct answer for it. The answer you get will depend on the person you are asking and here are some possible answers.

- It is a bad sign for the party and is setting up the Democrats for wins in the upcoming election
- It is a good sign for the party as it is getting rid of disloyal members and setting up to remove the Democrats from power.
- It is a sign that Trump still has power in the party and is on track to become the next president.
- It doesn't really mean anything as it was just a single election that didn't go as expected.

Those are just 4 quick examples I provided and depending on who you ask any of them can be said to be accurate and the others incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* question about future events is a speculation as long it's a question about what *may* happen.  If the question is about future events, in order for it not to be speculative, it must be about what *must* happen because of some *already known* information.
For example,

> now that X has been elected to the position Y, when will they assume the duties of that position?

would be a question about what is *already known*.  It's a question which can be answered based on the known process of assuming the office "Y".  *Process* is well-defined and documented somewhere.  So it is possible to learn before it actually happens.

Asking about future events based on guesses requires making assumptions about other events and making estimates.  This makes it an opinion.